# How to cover a view's foreground programmatically with a transculent color

Tags: android, android-view, android-seekbar

I want to cover views foregrounds with a **translucent** `CustomSeekBar` programmatically while it has this foreground:
`android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`
Because of my layouts are very complicated and there are lots of views to cover with a transculent color, I dont want to put my `CustomSeekBar` to each layout so many times and make them visible.
I want to have the ripple effect still after covering foreground.

It will raise from below of view like that:

[image: not covered]  [image: covered]

**Note :**
I have my `CustomSeekBar`.
The covering with translucent color means solution can be
1. setting a translucent color as foreground (but probably I will lose ripple effect)
2. inflating and putting a prepared view (`CustomSeekBar`) to each view I want. (I dont know how to do it)

I dont know how to do that.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: So do you want to set as foreground for your seekbar a translucent color?

Comment: No, I already have  my customSeekBar with translucent color. I just need to put it in front of some views. As I have too many views to put customSeekBar, I need to do it programmatically with or without custom seekbar, it doesn't matter. I have to get the exact vision.